# Sending pointers to functions

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, structure

In C, I am trying to allocate memory for a structure by sending a pointer to an independent function. I know that malloc() is required to allocate the memory, but I am a bit confused on the process.

If I have a function:

```
    void allocate(structure *ptr){
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr)); //ptr assigned memory block address 
    }
```

I am allocating a memory block equal to the size of the structure, but only to the copy of the original pointer sent to the function. When the function returns control to the calling function, ptr is lost and we now have a memory leak.

Essentially what I am trying to do is send a pointer, of a structure type, to a function and allocate the memory for the structure.

---

I know this can be done with something like:

```
    structure *allocate(structure *ptr)
```

Where the call is something to the affect of:

```
    some_struct_ptr = allocate(some_struct_ptr);
```

But how can it be done the other way?

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot simply return a pointer to the allocated memory?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
void allocate( structure **ptr )
{
     // Allocate memory for a single structure and put that address into the location
     // that ptr points to. ptr is assumed to be the address of the pointer given
     // by the caller

     *ptr = malloc( sizeof(structure) );
}
```

So when you want to return a value in a parameter, you need to pass that variable's address in, then assign the value to what that address points to. Since, in this case, the variable is a pointer, you are passing in the address of a pointer or, in other words, a pointer to a pointer. Then the assignment `*ptr =...` says to "assign an address to the pointer that this address points to".

Then to call it, you pass the ADDRESS of the pointer you want to be set:

```
structure *my_ptr;

// Put something useful in my_ptr, like the address of memory that will hold a structure
allocate( &my_ptr );
```

The important thing to remember in this case is that you are passing the *location of the pointer*, not the *location of the data* that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: I understand the function of the ampersand in this method, but what is actually happening? I am requesting a pointer (*) to a some pointer (*ptr) thereby requiring the syntax (**ptr). I understand this part. So when I write `*ptr = malloc ...` are we basically assigning the address of the memory block to whatever the pointer points to? That is, since the &my_ptr points to my_ptr, we are dereferencing &my_ptr and assigning the value stored in my_ptr to be the memory block address?

Comment: @sherrellbc I updated my description a bit with more explanation, See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) are values (often fitting in one word, or register, in your machine).

It is a good habit to always initialize pointers (perhaps to `NULL`).

A function like your `allocate` which takes some pointer and replaces immediately that pointer is losing the original pointer's value.

BTW, you probably have a

```
  typedef struct somestruct_st structure;
```

and I would prefer `structure_t` instead of `structure` as a type name.

So basically, your function behaves like

```
 void allocate(structure *ptrold){
    /// ptrold is never used in this function
    structure* ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));
}
```

Unless you do something with your local `ptr` your function is [leaking memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You probably should return that `ptr`, or put it into some location (perhaps a memory field inside some structure or some global variable)

A possible way might be to pass the address of your pointer, that is a pointer to pointers;

```
  void allocate (structure **pptr)
  {
     structure *oldptr = *pptr;
     /// etc...
  }
```

Of course you'll call `allocate(&someptr)` in that case.

My suggestion is to deal with pointers in a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style: avoid modifying them, just allocate them freshly: so I don't like `realloc` and I don't like passing addresses of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

for example if you are defined a structure type like this

```
   typedef struct abc
    {
    int a;
    char name[20];
    }abc_t;

   int  main()
    {
    abc_t *ptr=NULL;
    allocate(&ptr); // you are passing address of pointer , call by reference   
                    //things gets effected which made in function.
    }
```

you need to allocate the no of bytes that  an object of type `abc_t` requires.To allocate memory to a pointer in function you need define the function with double pointer.

```
 void allocate(abc_t **ptr) 
        {
        *ptr=(abc_t *)malloc(sizeof(abc_t)); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void allocate(structure *ptr){
     ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr)); //ptr assigned memory block address 
}
```

Here, ptr is a pointer to a structure. It stores the address of a set of elements that together constitute the class 'structure'. So sizeof(ptr) will return the number of bytes used to store the address of the structure but not the size of the structure itself.  Hence to allocate memory to store 1 unit of structure, you need to modify the statement to,

```
void allocate(structure *ptr){
     ptr = malloc(sizeof(structure)); //ptr assigned memory block address 
}
```

Further, to achieve, what you said by maintaining the return type of the function 'void', you can use call-by-reference mechanism of function call.

```
void allocate(structure **ptr){
     *ptr = malloc(sizeof(structure)); //ptr assigned memory block address 
}
```

The caller should call it as,

```
allocate(&ptr);
```